# How do I convert a data frame that takes in multiple columns to a single array?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a data frame that takes in multiple columns from a CSV file to a single array. Whenever I print out the transformed data frame, it prints out a 3 x m array instead of a 1 x m array. The code is shown below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('LAB 2 DATA.csv', sep=r'\s*,\s*', header=0, encoding='ascii', engine='python')

t_e = df[['heat 7', 'heat 1', 'heat 2']].to_numpy()
t_c = df[['heat 4','heat 5','heat 3','heat 6']].to_numpy()
```

Is there any way to combine the columns to a single array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for this. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df.stack().reset_index()[0]
>>>
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The content of your `df` is not given but I think this should apply.